Iterate to a nested list in a pythonic way
I have the following payload:
payload = [{
  "identification": {
    "corporationName": "Test",
    "code": 1234
  },
  "locations": [
     {
      "postalAddress": {
        "address": "St Test",
        "country": "US"
      },
      "availability" : {
          "standards": [
            {
              "weekday": "SUNDAY",
              "openingTime": "string",
              "closingTime": "string"
            }
          ],
          "isPublicAccessAllowed": false
      },
      "phones": [
        {
          "countryCallingCode": "55",
          "areaCode": "19",
          "number": "35721199"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]

I want to normalize this JSON in a list of dicts. I'm using:
def generate_values(r: dict):
        return (
            ('companyname', get(r, 'identification.corporationName', valueType=str)),
            ('companycode', get(r, 'identification.code', valueType=str)),
        )
    
_ = [dict_test[k].append(v) for r in payload for k, v in generate_values(r)]

NOTE: get is a method created by me to extract values from a JSON
My doubt is: If I have a list inside this payload (like locations), how can I change my list compreehension to iterate over this nested list and send this nested list to generate_values as a parameter?
I am expecting to return something like:
    return (
            ('companyname', get(r, 'identification.corporationName', valueType=str)),
            ('companycode', get(r, 'identification.code', valueType=str)),
            ('addressstreet', get(nested_list_payload, 'postalAddress.address',valueType=str)),
            ('adresscountry', get(nested_list_payload, 'postalAddress.country',valueType=str)),
            ('antohervalue', get(nested_nested_list, ...))
    )


Could you supply an example of the locations JSON list and what exactly you want the output to be?  It's hard to figure out exactly what your end goal is from the supplied code fragments (e.g. we don't know what get returns given those inputs, so making it part of the expected output isn't useful).

Why my question is closed since the sugested answer is a java script answer?

maybe don't use list comprehension but normal for-loop - and this allows to add print() to debug code. And later try to convert it to list comprehension. But usually complex structure may need to use recursion to work with nested element.

as for me you can't replace nested list in get() but your function get() first has to check nested elements to find postalAddress and later run code to get next element after dot.
